# bash to prefix and postfix special chars while adding elements to array

Tags: arrays, bash, arraylist

Team,
how to recreate an array with prefix and postfix chars is my requirement excluding first index.

I am creating one element string and somehow it is stipping off `s` . any way how can i avoid that? and is there a better way of adding what i want?

`elements_string="src/common src/common/access/ src/common/deny/"`

I am creating below `new` array holding all elements starting `index 1` to exclude index 0. then while adding them I want them to carry prefix and postfix.

```
for ele in $elements_string
do
    bazel_apps_list=$(find $ele -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort |uniq)
   new+=(-//${bazel_apps_list[@]:1}/...)
done
```

output: missing s letter from src.

```
-//rc/common/access/...
```

like this below see the prefix `-//` and postfix `...`

expected output
`new=(-//src/common/access/... -//src/common/deny/...)`

basically, I need to pass these to bazel coverage command so the need.

`bazel coverage ${new[@]}`

I tried below an answer

```
#!/bin/bash
apps_str="$(ls -d src/common/*/)"
echo $apps_str
if [ ! -z "${apps_str}" ]; then
    for APP in $apps_str
    do  
        bazel_apps_array=("$(find $APP -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort |uniq)")
        app_parent_dir=${bazel_apps_array[0]}
        app_child_dirs=${bazel_apps_array[@]:1}
        mapfile -t -d '' skip_app_child_dirs < <( find $app_child_dirs -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' -printf '-//%h/...\0' )
        #bazel coverage $app_parent_dir $skip_app_child_dirs
    echo -e "bazel coverage $app_parent_dir ${skip_app_child_dirs[@]}"
    done
else
    printf "\nAPP %s Parent dir is not bazel buildable, hence skip it.\n"
fi
```

output

```
src/common/access/ src/common/args/ src/common/zaputil/ 

./t.sh: line 10: mapfile: -d: invalid option
mapfile: usage: mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]

./t.sh: line 10: mapfile: -d: invalid option
mapfile: usage: mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
bazel src/common/access
.
.
.
```

expected output

```
bazel coverage src/common/access -//src/common/access/v1/... -//src/common/access/v2/...
```

Comment: Are you using bash, or zsh? In bash, `$elements_array` only gets the first element of the array. In either one, that assignment to `bazel_apps_list` is setting it as a plain string, not an array.

Comment: bash. actually my bad. `elements_array` is actually string. hence i did not use @. let me update code.

Comment: How about making `bazel_apps_list` an array? But even then, I think your code will break if `find` locates a BAZEL.build file inside a directory where the directory name contains a white space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your `bazel_apps_list` is a scalar (not an array), `${bazel_apps_list[@]}` is the same as `$bazel_apps_list`. And you apparently think that `${bazel_apps_list[@]:1}` expands as the first element of the array while it expands as `$bazel_apps_list` with the first character removed or, to be a bit more accurate, from the second character (numbered 1) to the end of the string (the default). If `bazel_apps_list` was an indexed array you would probably access its first element with `${bazel_apps_list[0]}`.

Anyway, GNU `find` (if it is the one you use) is so powerful that when your script runs it more than once and post-processes its output there is a chance that a much simpler solution exists with only one single invocation and no post-processing.

You can try:

```
elements_string=("src/common" "src/common/access/" "src/common/deny/")
mapfile -t -d '' new < <( find "${elements_string[@]}" -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' -printf '-//%h/...\0' )
```

We use an indexed array for `elements_string` instead of a string, the `-d ''` option of `mapfile` and the `-printf '...\0'` action of `find` just in case you have spaces or newline characters in your filenames. The two latter use the NUL character as separator, that is, the only character that cannot be found in filenames.

When passing the result to `bazel` do not forget the quotes around `${new[@]}` to get exactly one word per element even if you have spaces or newline characters:

```
bazel coverage "${new[@]}"
```

If it do not have spaces or newline characters in your filenames you can try the slightly simpler:

```
elements_string="src/common src/common/access/ src/common/deny/"
new=( $(find $elements_string -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' -printf '-//%h/...\n') )
```

Comment: thanks, i have a clarification, how are we skipping the first element in array case? I don't want first element of array to be passed to bazel after prefix/postfix is done to rest of the elements.

Comment: I am posting my entire program to help clarify my need better. please check next edit from this time.

Comment: To skip the first element of an indexed array just use `"${arr[@]:1}"` (if it is really an array, not a scalar). But how do you know that the element you want to skip is the first? I mean, how do you know the order in the `find` result? And if you think that it is `src/common` why don't you simply remove it from your list of directories to search?

Comment: Apparently your bash is too old for the `-d` option of `mapfile`. Forget it and use the simpler second solution I suggest if you do not have spaces or newlines in your filenames. And the new code you posted is uselessly complicated. The 2 lines I suggest are a replacement for your complete first attempt. No loops, no if, no else, no printf, no sed. Just these two lines.

Comment: The new code you show is extremely strange and I don't even understand what it is supposed to do. Could you edit again your answer to explain what you are trying to do, not with code examples but with plain English? Ideally add an example of file hierarchy and your expected output for this example.

Comment: thanks. second solution without map worked and I found no stripping of s from src. However, I will post another question with a follow up. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code is removing first symbol `${bazel_apps_list[@]:1}`, bazel_apps_list - is a variable not array, so you cutting first symbol from "src*"
You just need to change it to `$bazel_apps_list`. And if you need to start from index 1 you have to add a counter like this:

```
n=1
for ele in $elements_string
do
   bazel_apps_list=$(find $ele -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort |uniq)
   new[$n]="-//$bazel_apps_list/..."
   ((n++))
done
```